# Log4Net RollingFileAppender losing messages

Tags: c#, log4net, rollingfileappender

I am using log4net to log to files and for some reason, some log messages are lost, and always in the same spot. First my configuration:

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="aiAppender" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logs\import.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

The aiAppender, while defined, is not used.

The log pattern is that I initially burst log about 88 lines of which all are there. Then the missing log period starts and lasts approx 6 seconds. Then the logging continues and everything is logged from that point onward.

If I remove the burst logging and replace it with only a few log entries, nothing is lost.

Apparently RollingFileAppender can lose messages. I wasn't aware of that.

I am certain this is an issue with log4net, as I have a log-wrapper where I split my log messages to both log4net and to application insights (the aiAppender didn't do a good enough job for us) and application insights does receive the messages that log4net doesn't log.

Can I configure the RollingFileAppender to avoid losing messages?

Edit: The log wrapper logs first to log4net and then to application insights so it is not a question about the application insights logging that prevents log4net logging.

Comment: Are you writing to the log from multiple processes and/or threads? Have you tried [looking at the log4net internal logs](https://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/)?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Totally forgot about log4net internal logging. Haven't been able to reproduce it, though, but internal logging is enabled now.

Answer (score 0):

You can only debug this when you activate internal debugging. Active the debugger and see if for example log4net is reconfigured at some point.